# Not able to update the model with Angular UI and Modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am using angular and Bootstrap for angular ([angular UI](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)), and when I open the modal (click on Edit List) and the select a country to Edit, let say I change the name of a country, I don't see it reflected in the model of the modal controller. So this value is not updated: $ctrl.Country.

I am getting lost as I am using duoble binding in the input text: {{$ctrl.Country.Name}}

This is my Plunker

```
<a href="https://plnkr.co/edit/5JHKpdmLMVBFlmL22SGC?p=preview">Plunker</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/hVdZThGfHq79I0C0Vve7?p=preview) where some mistakes were fixed:

1. `<input type="text" class="form-control"
   ng-model="$ctrl.Country.Code">` and `<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.Country.Code">`: `ng-model` instead of `value`
2. `$ctrl.Save` was added:
3. `modalInstance.result.then`: logic was fixed